# Why does the PDOStatement return false on single fetch?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I don´t know why PHP returns always false, when I try to to execute a SELECT query with fetching a single row.

My tables are:

```
create table profile
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    email char(50) not null,
    password char(100) not null,
    name char(100) not null,
    surname char(50) not null,
    street char(50) not null,
    homeno char(5) not null,
    postalcode char(5),
    homearea char(100) not null,
    group_id int not null,
    primary key(id)
);
create table usergroups
(
    id int auto_increment not null,
    name char(30) not null,
    primary key(id)
);
```

I got some datasets in it and then I try to read them with (for fetching one user profile; simplified example):

```
$sSQL = <<<SQL
SELECT `profile`.`id` AS `profile.id`, `profile`.`email` AS `profile.email`, `profile`.`password` AS `profile.password`, `profile`.`name` AS `profile.name`, `profile`.`surname` AS `profile.surname`, `profile`.`street` AS `profile.street`, `profile`.`homeno` AS `profile.homeno`, `profile`.`postalcode` AS `profile.postalcode`
FROM `profile`
inner join `usergroups` on `profile`.`group_id` = `usergroups`.`id`
WHERE `profile`.`email` = ?
SQL;
$pdo = new PDO($sDsn, $sUser, $sPass);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sSQL);
$sEmail = 'some@example.com';
$stmt->bindValue(1, $sEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($result);
```

My database is a MariaDB.

The same query has worked before without a question mark in it, so there was nothing to bind before. I  guess there is an mistake with database and/or PHP.

Comment: Have you tried echoing the value of `$sSQL`? You could then run that directly in, say, phpMyAdmin or similar to confirm the query itself is valid.

Comment: Yes. As I wrote above, the query works without a question mark, so I meant with a fixed string e. g. like ``profile`.`email` = 'some@example.com'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programming is not something like fiction literature. Every premise have to be verified.

```
$pdo = new PDO($sDsn, $sUser, $sPass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sSQL = SELECT p.* FROM profile inner join usergroups u on group_id = u.id 
        WHERE email = 'some@example.com';
$user = $pdo->query($sSQL)->fetch();
var_dump($user);

$sSQL = SELECT p.* FROM profile inner join usergroups u on group_id = u.id 
        WHERE email = ?;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sSQL);
$stmt->execute(['some@example.com']);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($user);
```

run this code and paste result here. Or just consider it yourself

Comment: Ok, thanks. In my larger class I used to fetch a column, that does not exist. I just removed it and everything works fine. Thanks for your help. In future I will always turn Exception throwing for PDO to on.